# Jquery if div doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using 1 js for 2 different pages. 1 page doesn't have a div which the other does. So when I submit the values, I get a `$(` js error

for

```
$('.description'+save_id+'').html(description_val).show(); //update category description
```

I suspect that I get the error because there is nothing to show(). Is there a short code I can use to detect if the div.description exists otherwise don't do the function?

Comment: jQuery methods don't complain when there are no matches to the selector. Are you sure you have jQuery loaded for that page? If you don't, you'll get a *"`$` is undefined"* error.

Comment: Yes I have jquery because other function work

Comment: It won't matter if there aren't any `.description` elements on the page. You won't get an error. But what is the value of `description_val`? If *that* is undefined, it will fail.

Comment: @patrick dw - description val is the variable, `var description_val = $('.edit_description'+save_id+'').val();` which extracts the value from a text input with class .edit_description (+ a unique id - the save_id) So that input isn't on the page. You think that's causing the error?

Comment: If `.edit_description` isn't on the page, then calling `.val()` will return `undefined` and will cause the code in your question to fail. I'll add an answer to give a workaround that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `description_val` variable is `undefined`, then the code will fail.

Try using an `if()` statement to only run the code if `description_val` is not `undefined`.

```
if(description_val) {
    $('.description'+save_id+'').html(description_val).show();
}
```

Or if for some reason the value of `description_val` may be a value that would equate to `false`, then do this:

```
if(description_val !== undefined) {
    $('.description'+save_id+'').html(description_val).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery will not error if it has nothing to perform on. The `show()` would not be a problem. To answer your question, though, you can check the `length` property on the jQuery object returned from `$`.

Comment: In other words: `if ($('.description'+save_id).length === 0) { ... }`

Comment: How would I check the length? But, `.description'+save_id+` in the js is for a div `.description14 or .description12.. etc` which doesn't exist on the page. While show() isn't the issue, do you think it's the div?

Comment: @Cyber Junkie, What problem are you experiencing?  You're being unclear.  `.show()` and `.html()` work even if no element is selected by `$(...)`; they just do nothing.

Comment: Sorry. I have a div `.description` in my html and the javascript picks up its value, puts it in an text input and on submit it returns the divs html using show(). On a different page I don't have the .description div or input so I get the `$(` errors, I think because there's no `.description` in the HTML. So how can I disable this line.. `$('.description'+save_id+'').html(description_val).show();` if there is no .description div and input. I have different pages which use some functions from the js file and others that don't. So I don't want to create separate js for each page.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted I'd check to make sure the variables you're using are all defined at this stage.  To check for existence you can do this:

```
if ($('.description' + save_id).size() > 0) {
  // code here that operates on the div.
}
```

This is essentially just a syntactic alternative to checking the length property.